# Xfce4 change internal name of launcher or let launcher show all items instead of a menu

Tags: xfce

When adding a launcher to a panel in Xfce4, the launcher is called just "launcher" in the panel items configuration with a flyout text like "Internal name: launcher-12". Neither is very helpful when there are several launchers in the panel.

Alternatively I could add many programs to one launcher, but then the launcher shows only the icon of one of the programs plus an indication in form of an arrow icon that there is a menu with more items.

Is there a way to (a) get an icon for each program to launch and (b) easily identify the launcher in the items configuration menu? I can see two ways:

a) The launcher shows all items and I use just one launcher for all of them.
b) The launcher's internal name can be set.

I cannot find either way with Xfce 4.10. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you 'll have to add multiple launchers for each item